# How to Fix Eigen::NaturalOrdering<int> >::MatrixType' has no member named 'isCompressed'

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen

I want to use SparseQR or SparseLU method for solving linear systems with sparse matrices. I am using Eigen Library for that purpose. The problem is that this methods gives error an the code doesnt work.
I am programing in Eclipse C++, with MinGW compiler

I have used the bicgstab method from the Eigen Library and it is working, but now with the Sparse methods errors appear.

This is the code I want to use for solving linear systems, just changing the method name and one of the parameters it works for other methods, but not for sparse methods

```
SparseQR<MatrixXd, NaturalOrdering<int>> solver;
solver.analyzePattern(A);
solver.factorize(A);
x = solver.solve(y);
```

x,A and y are of the class MatrixXd.

This code works for the method bicgstab, and the syntaxis is the same. The problem is that the following error appears:

> ```
> src\/src/SparseQR/SparseQR.h:381:66: error: 'const class
> Eigen::SparseQR<Eigen::Matrix<double, -0x000000001,
> -0x000000001>,Eigen::NaturalOrdering<int> >::MatrixType' has no member named 'isCompressed'
>
> src\/src/SparseQR/SparseQR.h:381:66: error: 'const class
> Eigen::SparseQR<Eigen::Matrix<double, -0x000000001,
> -0x000000001>,Eigen::NaturalOrdering<int> >::MatrixType' has no member named 'outerIndexPtr'
> ```

and I dont know hot fix it.

If you have any idea of a possible solution I would really appreciate it. Thanks for your time

Comment: `SparseQR` is intended to solve **sparse** systems, i.e., `A` (and the first template parameter of `SparseQR`) needs to be sparse.

Comment: A sparse method requires a sparse matrix.

Comment: Maybe my question is wrongly explained. Suppose the matrix A,, although it is a MatrixXd, it is still sparse, as I have created it with a sparse method. Solvers accept MatrixXd as inputs. The problem is in the NaturalOrdening, where those members are missing in the SparseQR method. I have tried changing to:     SparseQR<SparseMatrix<double>, NaturalOrdering<int>> solver;                      but the problem is the same as previously explained.

Comment: No, the problem is that the matrix `A` is of  `MatrixXd` type. It must be a matrix of the type `SparseMatrix<>`, and it must moreover be a *compressed* sparse matrix. In addition, the template parameter of SparseQR must be corrected, as explained by  @chtz

Comment: I wrote an answer, if that does not solve your problem, provide a [mre] of what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, `SparseQR` only works with sparse matrices. If for some reason your input matrix `A` is passed as a dense matrix, you could convert it using `A.sparseView()`, but you should really prefer storing it as a (compressed) sparse matrix in the first place. Also notice that the template parameter of `SparseQR` must be a `SparseMatrix`:

```
void foo(Eigen::MatrixXd const &A, Eigen::VectorXd const &y, Eigen::VectorXd& x)
{
    Eigen::SparseQR<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>, Eigen::NaturalOrdering<int> > solver;
    solver.compute(A.sparseView());
    x = solver.solve(y);
}
```

If your matrix `A` in fact is dense (or "not very sparse") it is usually much more efficient to just use a dense solver, e.g.

```
void foo(Eigen::MatrixXd const &A, Eigen::VectorXd const &y, Eigen::VectorXd& x)
{
    Eigen::FullPivHouseholderQR<Eigen::MatrixXd> solver;
    solver.compute(A);
    x = solver.solve(y);
}
```

Comment: @RHertel true, but the information given by the OP is quite sparse ^^. I'll add a sentence that one could as well use a dense solver.

Comment: Perhaps it is noteworthy that, for the special case of SparseQR, the matrix must be compressed and of column-major storage order. http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SparseQR.html

Comment: @santimiq The "NaturalOrdering" error is where the problem manifests, but not where it is originated. The `NaturalOrdering` parameter makes no sense for a non-sparse matrix of the type `MatrixXd`. Try the solution that has been posted, you will see that it works.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for your help. It works now I think. Thank you again xd